# Extract column values from a list in a list

Tags: python, list

I have the following list in a list structure [image: 1]

How can i extract the data from all the rows in the first column (48.0, 48.01, 48.02, ...)

I expected: results[0:4][0] would extract the first 3 rows from the first column but it doesn't work, can someone explain why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If your data is a `list` containing `lists`, use a list-comprehension

  ```
  first_col = [sublist[0] for sublist in values]
  ```
- If your data is a `numpy` array, you can use its multi-level slicing

  ```
  first_col = values[:, 0]
  ```

---

```
values = [list(range(10)), list(range(10)), list(range(10)), list(range(10)), ]

first_col = [sublist[0] for sublist in values]
print(first_col)  # [0, 0, 0, 0]

import numpy as np
values = np.array(values)
first_col = values[:, 0]
print(first_col)  # [0 0 0 0]
```

Comment: I tried your method but i get an index error: https://imgur.com/a/yU2aiGl

Comment: @NielsdeVries that means you have an empty list somewhere, do ` [sublist[0] for sublist in values if sublist]`

Comment: Thank you very much! Ya u were right i indeed had 2 empty rows on the end.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use

```
result = [lst[0] for lst in results]
```